# LWC Conditional render to show a field in a data table if that field has value

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, table, conditional

I'm trying to show or not show the content of field in a data table depending on if it is null or empty etc. What am I doing wrong?

```
<th scope="col">
          <div lwc:if={isNotes}>
               <a href="#" data-id={task.Id} onclick={clickViewTask} data-index={index}>{task.Name} Notes </a>     
          </div>
 </th>
```

```
LWC .js

@wire(getList, { retId: '$recordId'})  //a3Z8K000001bxakUAA
          contactRec(result)
          {
            this.taskResult = result;
            
                if(result.error){
                    console.log('error is#'+result.error);
                    this.error = result.error;
                }
                else if(result.data){
                    this.lsttasklist = result.data;
                    let tempArray = [];
                    for(let i=0; i<this.lsttasklist.length; i++)
                    {
                        tempArray.push({Id:this.lsttasklist[i].Id,
                                    Owner_Name__c:this.lsttasklist[i].Owner_Name__c,
                                    Name:this.lsttasklist[i].Name,
                                    Risk_Event__r:this.lsttasklist[i].Risk_Event__r,
                                    RiskEventName:this.lsttasklist[i].Risk_Event__r.Name,
                                    Phase__c :this.lsttasklist[i].Phase__c,
                                    Task__c:this.lsttasklist[i].Task__c,
                                    Task_Name__c:this.lsttasklist[i].Task_Name__c,
                                    Task_Status__c:this.lsttasklist[i].Task_Status__c,
                                    Notes_Log__c:this.lsttasklist[i].Notes_Log__c,
                                    Started_Date__c:this.lsttasklist[i].Started_Date__c,
                                    Closed_Date__c:this.lsttasklist[i].Closed_Date__c,
                                    Risk_Event__c:this.lsttasklist[i].Risk_Event__c,
                                    IsExpanded:false, isNotes:false,
                                    ButtonLabel:"+"});
                    }
                    this.tasklist = tempArray;
                    if (tempArray.Notes_Log__c != null)
                    {
                        this.isNotes = true;
                    } 
            }
            
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (tempArray.Notes_Log__c != null)
```

Will never be true. You'll need to check if a record has the value, as in:

```
this.isNotes = tempArray.some(record => !!record.Notes_Log__c);
```

Comment: I've tried this:

if (tempArray.Notes_Log__c != null)
                    {
                      this.isNotes = tempArray.some(record => !!record.Notes_Log__c);
                      
                    } 

and this:

this.isNotes = tempArray.some(record => !!record.Notes_Log__c);

and this:

this.tasklist.isNotes = tempArray.some(record => !!record.Notes_Log__c);

None of them work. Can you be more specific?